# apply a self-written function to a column containing spacy objects

Tags: python, pandas, spacy

I'm trying to apply a self-written function to a column containing spacy objects (processed text).

Consider the following example. I have a sentence: `sent = 'Dies ist ein generischer Satz mit einem bestimmten Wort und anderen Worten.'`

I process this sentence with spacy and apply a matcher detecting the words "Wort" und "Worten":

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_lg")

processed_sentence = nlp(sent)
matcher = spacy.matcher.Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pttrn: list = [[{'LOWER': "wort"}], [{'LOWER': "worten"}]]
matcher.add(1021, pttrn)

matches = matcher(processed_sentence)
```

I now want to print the matched words (my actual data contains multiple complicated patterns and I need to check they're working as intended). For one sentence, this is straightforward:

```
for match_id, start_match, end_match in matches:
    match_span = processed_sentence[start_match:end_match]
    print(match_span.text)
# Wort
# Worten
```

My actual data, however, are 10k+ sentences in a pandas data frame. I want to apply the same logic.
I think (I am happy to be corrected) a function is the easiest way:

```
def token_from_spacy_match(match_tuples, spacy_sentence):
    """ Takes in a list of tuples, each match_id, match_start, match_end; also takes in a processed sentence (spaCy doc). Returns list of matched words
    """

return_object: list = []  # list to hold all words of matches

for tup in match_tuples:  # iterate through tuples in match_tuples
    match_span = spacy_sentence[tup[1]:tup[2]]
    return_object.append(match_span.text)
    
return return_object
```

This works well on the initial sentence:

```
token_from_spacy_match(matches, processed_sentence)
# ['Wort', 'Worten']
```

I now want to apply this to a dataframe of sentences.

```
import pandas as pd    
df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame({'num': [1, 2],
                                 'sentence': ['Generischer Satz mit einem bestimmten Wort und anderen Worten.',
                                              'Hier nur ein bestimmtes Wort.']})
df['spacy_sent= [doc for doc in nlp.pipe(df['sentence'].tolist())]
df['matches'] = df['spacy_sent'].apply(matcher)
```

This works.

But applying the above function to the columns doesn't work:

```
df['matchwords'] = df['spacy_sent'].apply(token_from_spacy_match, df['matches'], df['spacy_sent'])
# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

My desired outcome is:

```
num  sentence      spacy_sent    matches                          matchwords
1    Dies ist...   Dies ist...   [(1021, 8, 9), (1021, 11, 12)]   ['Wort', 'Worten']
2    Hier nur...   Hier nur...   [(1021, 4, 5)]                   ['Wort']
```

How do I achieve this? Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, this is what you actually want:

```
df['matchwords'] = df.apply(lambda x: token_from_spacy_match(x['matches'], x['spacy_sent']), axis=1)
```